# vectorizing a script with cellfun

Tags: matlab, loops, cell

I'm aiming to import data from various folder and text files into matlab.

```
clear all
main_folder = 'E:\data';
    %Directory of data
TopFolder = dir(main_folder);
    %exclude the first two cells as they are just pointers. 
TopFolder = TopFolder(3:end);
TopFolder = struct2cell(TopFolder);
Name1 = TopFolder(1,:);
    %obtain the name of each folder
dirListing = cellfun(@(x)dir(fullfile(main_folder,x,'*.txt')),Name1,'un',0);
Variables = cellfun(@(x)struct2cell(x),dirListing,'un',0);
FilesToRead = cellfun(@(x)x(1,:),Variables,'un',0);
    %obtain the name of each text file in each folder
```

This provides the name for each text file in each folder within 'main_folder'. I am now trying to load the data without using a for loop (I realise that for loops are sometimes faster in doing this but I'm aiming for a compact script).

The method I would use with a for loop would be:

```
for k = 1:length(FilesToRead);
    filename{k} = cellfun(@(x)fullfile(main_folder,Name{k},x),FilesToRead{k},'un',0);
    fid{k} = cellfun(@(x)fopen(x),filename{k},'un',0);
    C{k} = cellfun(@(x)textscan(x,'%f'),fid{k},'un',0);
end
```

Is there a method which would involve not using loops at all? something like cellfun within cellfun maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
folder = 'E:\data';
files = dir(fullfile(folder, '*.txt'));
full_names = strcat(folder, filesep, {files.name});
fids = cellfun(@(x) fopen(x, 'r'), full_names);
c = arrayfun(@(x) textscan(x, '%f'), fids);  % load data here
res = arrayfun(@(x) fclose(x), fids);
assert(all(res == 0), 'error in closing files');
```

but if the data is in csv format it can be even easier:

```
folder = 'E:\data';
files = dir(fullfile(folder, '*.txt'));
full_names = strcat(folder, filesep, {files.name});
c = cellfun(@(x) csvread(x), full_names,  'UniformOutput', false);
```

now all the data is stored in `c`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This it going to be pretty scary since C depends on fid depends on filename. The basic idea will be:

```
deal(feval(@(filenames_fids){filenames_fids{1}, filenames_fids{2}, ...
  <compute C>}, feval(@(filenames){filenames, <compute fid>}, ...
  <compute filenames>)));
```

Let's start with computing the filenames:

```
arrayfun(@(x)cellfun(@(x)fullfile(main_folder,Name{k},x),FilesToRead{k},...
  'un',0), 1:length(FilesToRead), 'uniformoutput', 0);
```

this will give us a K-by-1 cell array of filenames. Now we can use that to compute fids:

```
{filenames, arrayfun(@(k)cellfun(@(x)fopen(x),filenames{k},'un',0), ...
  1:length(FilesToRead), 'uniformoutput', 0)};
```

We stick fids together with filenames in a K-by-2 cell array, ready to pass on to compute our final outputs:

```
{filenames_fids{1}, filenames_fids{2}, ...
  arrayfun(@(k)cellfun(@(x)textscan(x,'%f'), ...
  filenames_fid{2}{k},'un',0), 1:length(FilesToRead), 'uniformoutput', 0)}
```

Then we're putting that final cell array into deal, so that the results end up in three different variables.

```
[filenames fid C] = deal(feval(@(filenames_fids){filenames_fids{1}, ...
  filenames_fids{2}, arrayfun(@(k)cellfun(@(x)textscan(x,'%f'), ...
  filenames_fid{2}{k},'un',0), 1:length(FilesToRead), 'uniformoutput', 0)}, ...
  feval(@(filenames){filenames, arrayfun(@(k)cellfun(@(x)fopen(x), ...
  filenames{k},'un',0), 1:length(FilesToRead), 'uniformoutput', 0)}, ...
  arrayfun(@(x)cellfun(@(x)fullfile(main_folder,Name{k},x),FilesToRead{k}, ...
  'un',0), 1:length(FilesToRead), 'uniformoutput', 0))));
```

Errm... There's probably a nicer way to do this if you don't mind about keeping `filenames` and `fid`. Maybe using cellfun instead of arrayfun could also make it more concise, but I'm not very good with cellfuns, so this is what I came up with. I think the `for` loop version is more compact anyway! (also, I haven't actually tested this. It will probably need some debugging).

Comment: I agree, the loop version seems to be way more compact.